# tangent point between 2 parabolas (parameter)

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functions, systems-of-equations, tangent-line

I have 2 parabolas: $P1: y=x^{2}+5x+4 $ and $P2: y=(m-1)x^{2}+(4m+n-4)x+5m+2n-4$ with $m,n$ real numbers and $m$ different from 1.

I need to find parameters $m,n$ such that these 2 parabolas are tangent in $T(-2,-2)$The right answer is $m=-2;n=1$

I started like this: $P1=P2$ and I got a quadratic equation $(2-m)x^{2}+(9-4m-n)x+8-5m-2n=0$

I put the condition that the discriminant to  be 0 but the calculation are too heavy.How to continue?

Comment: Is the point of contact given to you?

Comment: I think I don't understant the question.At first exercise I found m and n such that "C(1,10) is the only common point between parabolas but the parabolas aren't tangent."

Comment: Is the point $T(-2,-2)$n in the wording of the problem,   having to be an  intersection point of the parabolas?

Comment: Yes, the point is in the wording of the problem.I mean, the problem sounds:The parabolas are tangent in T(-2,-2) point if: m=? n=?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fact that $(-2,-2)$ is on $P2$,

$-2=(m-1)4+(4m+n-4)(-2)+5m+2n-4=m.$

Comment: Thank you for your response!What about n?It vanishes and I can't find it.

Comment: I found it from $P_{2}'$ Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the slope of a tangent to $P1$ is $2x+5$, which is $1$ when $x=-2.$  Now that we know $m=-2$, the slope of a tangent to $P2$ is $-6x-12+n$, which is $n$ when $x=-2.$

Answer (score 1):

Solve the following system:
$$P_2(-2)=-2$$ and $$P_2'(-2)=P_1'(-2).$$